# Dynamically changing a label based of a session/state variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to be able to change a link on my page dynamically based on whether the user is logged in or not.

So on the home page when the user first loads they can click the link to log in page and it directs them there to log in. After they are logged in id like to change the text to "log out", which I can do at the moment. But when the user clicks that same link it takes them to the log in page. Id like for this link to change based on whether my session variable is logged in or not.

So the below code changes the text for me once a user is logged in and re directs to the home page. How can i Change this session for when they click the login link again it logs them out like 'Session["LoggedIn"] = log out and change the text again

Thanks in advance

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["LoggedIn"] = emailTxtBx.Text;

    Response.Redirect("~/UL/Home.aspx");
}

if (Session["LoggedIn"] != null)
{
    loggedInLbl.Text = Session["LoggedIn"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
If (Session["LoggedIn"] != null)
{
        labelTxt.NavigateUrl = "~/webpage.aspx";
        labelTxt.Text = "LoggedIn";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User ViewBags

in Controller

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["LoggedIn"] = emailTxtBx.Text;
    ViewBag.Message = "This is Login Message";       
    Response.Redirect("~/UL/Home.aspx");
}
```

in View

```
if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div>
        <span>
            @ViewBag.Message
        </span>
    </div>  
}
```

The View Bag Help you to pass a message to View and you can use it to make a label dynamically